# how many transactions we can go in a personal blockchain made with geth ( go-ethereum ) per second or per block?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, golang

If I made a personal blockchain using `https://geth.ethereum.org/`, how many transactions can one block handle?

Answer (score 1):

This is a tricky question.

It depends on your blockchain's `blockGaslimit` && transaction's `gasCost`

For example, if your `blockGasLimit` is **6_000_000** gas and the transaction in question is complex and its `gasCost` is **1_000_000** gas. You can stack only 6 such transactions in each block minted.

Comment: means max number of transaction is `math.floor( blockGasLimit / gasCost )`

Comment: Yes, if the cost of all the transactions is always the same. What is not often the case.
I think this link will help you better grasp the subject https://shardeum.org/blog/what-is-a-gas-limit/